# HTTP 302 redirect with full HTML page in the payload

Tags: http, http-status-code-302

Why would a site respond with an HTTP 302 (redirect) and include HTML in the payload.  Check out godaddy.com.  You will need an account to log in.  When you log in you will see in an HTTP trace (I use firebug), a 302 returned with the location: header as expected, however the payload includes the complete HTML page.  Next, as expected,  you see the URL from the location header fetched with the same HTML payload.  Why would they do that?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anythign about GoDaddy but it may be a way to somewhat post information back to their server but not force your browser to do an "auto form post".  I'm working with ADFS currently and with that security (and many others) the authentication authority sends back a 200 with html of a form, which when loaded immediately posts that form to your server.

I'm currently experimenting with sending back a 302 with the payload that redirects back to the server instead.  This prevents a flash of white as that auto-post is taking place.

It's just a guess :)